# SVG Not Showing in Firefox and IE

Tags: firefox, svg, cross-browser

I have a svg element as follows:

```
<svg height="30px" width="30px" y="-15" x="-20">
<g>
<defs width="30px" height="30px" id="imgdefs">
<pattern y="0" x="0" width="1" height="1" id="circlePattern">
<image xlink:href="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_x0rFQvgE2sZmSRnExdHbC6kwDjB-wsBb1mHW_hHEeypPwELF9mHbS9rE7RI-wRWRpRkd3-0oksR1HOq6PuzRmTO63sRtHYTb9uzX58IIoUaOGesRsj_ELqLVTf3CTY9nxflIGYQ1lZ5" width="30px" height="30px" y="0" x="0">
</image>
</pattern>
</defs><circle fill="url(#circlePattern)" cy="15" cx="15" r="15px">
</circle>
</g>
</svg>
```

It shows up in Chrome but does not show up in Firefox 40, nor IE 11.  Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: try adding namespace declaration `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` on root svg tag

Comment: It works for me on Firefox as an html page. Is that what you're serving it as? If not you'll need maioman's solution.

Comment: And if you load it in an HTMLImage (`<img>') element, the external image won't load, thus nothing will be visible.